# Quote source - "if memories could bleed, if dreams could scream"

Tags: quote-source

we’re all killers.
we’ve all killed parts of ourselves
to survive.

we’ve all got blood on our hands.
something somewhere had to die
so we could stay alive.

if memories could bleed, if dreams could scream | m.a.w

Comment: Welcome to the site. what research have you done? Where did you first encounter the quote? Who/what is m.a.w.? Any information could be useful.

Comment: Could you please add where you found this and whether these three lines are a single continuous quote? (I found something similar on [Tumblr](https://aridanvte.tumblr.com/post/152307949746/if-memories-could-bleed-if-dreams-could-scream) and [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/687150855621901374/).)

Comment: I am guessing the origin of these quotes are from : https://www.tumblr.com/tagged/dvoyd?sort=top here it states that 'Dvoyd' a tumblr user who claims to be a 'writer' wrote these quotes himself and they have been reposted and shared multiple times by many people. I am not a hundred percent sure though but this comes up when I search these on the internet: https://dvoyd.tumblr.com/post/143460714298/amp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@dvoyd from tumblr here. 'Quote' source (it's more of poetry than a quote) is myself. It's freelance poetry that I have written and posted on tumblr for 5+ years now. If the quote ends with 'm.a.w' (those are my initials, yes) and it shows up in my writing tag on tumblr ([here](https://dvoyd.tumblr.com/tagged/skyler+scribbles)) then it's my work.

Comment: Just a question, since you were mentioned in the comments as the suspected original source, how did you come to find this question and site?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that googling that line gets a thousand hits.

The bad news is that they are almost all quotations posted without credit, as if written by the poster, that so many people seem to enjoy throwing around at each other.

Excluding tumblr and pinterest sites, there are fewer than a hundred hits.
Unfortunately all the ones I checked seem to be just as illiterate.

This is the largest such quotation I could find:

> we’re all killers.
> we’ve all killed parts of ourselves
> to survive.
>
> we’ve all got blood on our hands.
> something somewhere had to die
> so we could stay alive.
>
> if memories could bleed, if dreams could scream | m.a.w
>
> — [Quote – kingofthewindblog](https://kingofthewindblog.wordpress.com/type/quote/#post-417)

Comment: This link seems to work, but I'm unclear on where it is sourcing the quote from. Do the italics in the last line mean it's from a work called "*if memories could bleed, if dreams could scream*" by m.a.w.?

Comment: @bobble, I would guess that "maw" is the authors initials, but don't really know. On the other hand, @-chameleon's suggestion of [we’re all killers. we’ve all killed parts of...](https://dvoyd.tumblr.com/post/143460714298/amp) seems like a good candidate.  Most of these tumbler/pinterest/etc. sites are more than my brain can handle (and I'd like to keep it that way).